# Unable to change the records parameter in jqgrid and reload data using array storage and server side pagination

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to integrate jqgrid on my xhtml page and using the server side pagination support on click of 'next', 'prev' buttons on the jqgrid pager. I want to refresh grid with data stored in an array in a variable on page on click of 'next'/'prev' buttons but if I use 'local' as datatype, I am not able to set the 'records' parameter in the grid.  My code is as given below -

```
function reloadJQGrid(){

    $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
    $("#list").setGridParam({localReader:{repeatitems: false}});

    var myData1 ="{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":50,\"rows\":[" +
        "{\"id\":\"1\",\"examineeid\":\"123455\",\"firstname\":\"testfirst1\",\"middlename\":\"middle1\",\"lastname\":\"testlast1\",\"dateofbirth\":\"2007-10-01\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"emailaddress\":\"test1@test.com\",\"customfield1\":\"nodata\",\"customfield2\":\"nodata\",\"customfield3\":\"nodata\",\"customfield4\":\"nodata\",\"createdby\":\"dfgdfg\",\"createddate\":\"2007-10-01\",\"modifiedby\":\"try\",\"modifieddate\": \"2007-10-01\",\"accountname\":\"TRGG\",\"legacyexamineeid\":\"1234\",\"legacysystem\":\"test1\",\"groups\":\"testgroup\"}," +
        "{\"id\":\"2\",\"examineeid\":\"123\",\"firstname\":\"testfirst1\",\"middlename\":\"middle1\",\"lastname\":\"testlast1\",\"dateofbirth\":\"2007-10-01\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"emailaddress\":\"test1@test.com\",\"customfield1\":\"nodata\",\"customfield2\":\"nodata\",\"customfield3\":\"nodata\",\"customfield4\":\"nodata\",\"createdby\":\"ifgfg\",\"createddate\":\"2007-10-01\",\"modifiedby\":\"itr\",\"modifieddate\": \"2007-10-01\",\"accountname\":\"YTTT\",\"legacyexamineeid\":\"1234\",\"legacysystem\":\"rdtr\",\"groups\":\"testgroup\"}" +
        "] }";

    $("#list").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
    $("#list").setGridParam({data:myData1});
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Any pointers on this would help, I tried to use data type as 'json', this works with a json file with data in it, but I do not want to create a temporary file with json data, instead my variable gets refreshed with data, I want to use the same to reload the next set of data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the jqGrid [Options wiki page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions), "Records" is an read-only property.

Please try something like this as last steps in your "reloadJQGrid" function.

```
var records = 5000; //read this value from your server return string
$("#list").setGridParam({recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of "+records});
```

After the update your function will look like below:

```
function reloadJQGrid(){
    $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
    $("#list").setGridParam({localReader:{repeatitems: false}});
    var myData1 ="{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":50,\"rows\":[" + 
        "{\"id\":\"1\",\"examineeid\":\"123455\",\"firstname\":\"testfirst1\",\"middlename\":\"middle1\",\"lastname\":\"testlast1\",\"dateofbirth\":\"2007-10-01\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"emailaddress\":\"test1@test.com\",\"customfield1\":\"nodata\",\"customfield2\":\"nodata\",\"customfield3\":\"nodata\",\"customfield4\":\"nodata\",\"createdby\":\"dfgdfg\",\"createddate\":\"2007-10-01\",\"modifiedby\":\"try\",\"modifieddate\": \"2007-10-01\",\"accountname\":\"TRGG\",\"legacyexamineeid\":\"1234\",\"legacysystem\":\"test1\",\"groups\":\"testgroup\"}," +
        "{\"id\":\"2\",\"examineeid\":\"123\",\"firstname\":\"testfirst1\",\"middlename\":\"middle1\",\"lastname\":\"testlast1\",\"dateofbirth\":\"2007-10-01\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"emailaddress\":\"test1@test.com\",\"customfield1\":\"nodata\",\"customfield2\":\"nodata\",\"customfield3\":\"nodata\",\"customfield4\":\"nodata\",\"createdby\":\"ifgfg\",\"createddate\":\"2007-10-01\",\"modifiedby\":\"itr\",\"modifieddate\": \"2007-10-01\",\"accountname\":\"YTTT\",\"legacyexamineeid\":\"1234\",\"legacysystem\":\"rdtr\",\"groups\":\"testgroup\"}" +
        "] }";
    $("#list").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
    $("#list").setGridParam({data:myData1});
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    var records = 5000; //read this value from your server return string
    $("#list").setGridParam({recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of "+records});
```

}

Comment: Thanks Yogendra, this works. As of now, we have changed the function to fetch the complete JSON from backend. We are using Jboss Seam on server side.